# How can I use pandas to find only rows with differing column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing a single column ('label') from several nearly identical cvs files.

I've written some code that creates a new data frame from the files that I am comparing:

```
def main(argv):


    dirs = sys.argv[1:]
    print ("Directorys to process:"+ str(dirs))
    files = glob.glob(dirs[0]+"/*.csv")
    files = [f.replace(dirs[0]+"/","") for f in files]
    print ("files to process:"+str(files))

    dfList =[dirs]
    dfLabel = pd.DataFrame()
    resultdf = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in  range( 0,len(files)):
        filename = files[file]
        for index in range(0,len(dirs)):
            dirname = dirs[index]
            dfItem = pd.read_csv(dirname+"/"+filename)
            resultdf[dirname] = dfItem['label']
        resultdf.fillna(value=0, inplace=True) 
        resultdf['mode_average'] = resultdf.mode(axis=1)
        # new step to remove rows where all values are equal
        resultdf.to_csv("Comparison_of_"+filename,index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

This works the way I want it to, but I am really only interested in seeing the rows where one of my input files is different.  I am expecting them to be the same in most cases, and there are hundreds or thousands of rows.  Is there a built in way to evaluate and return only the rows where one or more of the values in that row are different? The number of files  and directories that I run comparisons on may fluctuate.

Comment: do I understand right that you want to collect all unique rows across many CSV files in a single file/dataframe?

Comment: If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, it makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I want to collect unique rows of the DataFrame that was formed when I collected the label column from several files.   Example is there are 3 directories, A, B C.  Each contain   file1.csv and that contains a label column.  The label column contents are always either blank, or contain a one or a two.  In this example lets have the file1 in A and C be identical. In A and B every 4th row has a 2. The file1.csv in directory B is almost identical, but in 3 instances there is nothing marked instead of the two.  I want to find those three rows.  The result should contain the original row index.

Comment: *Clarification of the above example.  In A and C, every 4th row has a 2.

Comment: One way that I might be able to get the answer that I need would be to return the row index where any column does not match the mode_average column.  Can I use itterows() to find that?

Comment: I ended up using pandasql to get the answer
`for index in range(0,len(dirs)):
        dirname = dirs[index]
        q = "select _ROWID_,* from resultdf where "+ dirname +" != mode_average"
        diffs = pysqldf(q)     if (len(diffs) >0):
            print (dirname+ " had deviations in "+filename)
            diffs.to_csv(dirname+"_"+filename+"_deviation.csv",index = False) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the help of pandasql.

This report shows the row number and the the comparison of the results of all of the labels where one did not match the mode average.

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys,glob
import getopt
import pandasql
from pandas import *
from pandasql import sqldf


dirs = sys.argv[1:]
print ("Directorys to process:"+ str(dirs))
files = glob.glob(dirs[0]+"/*.csv")
files = [f.replace(dirs[0]+"/","") for f in files]
print ("files to process:"+str(files))
dfList =[dirs]
resultdf = pd.DataFrame()
for file in  range( 0,len(files)):
    filename = files[file]
    for index in range(0,len(dirs)):
       dirname = dirs[index]
       dfItem = pd.read_csv(dirname+"/"+filename)
       resultdf[dirname] = dfItem['label']
    resultdf.fillna(value=0, inplace=True) 
    resultdf['mode_average'] = resultdf.mode(axis=1)
    pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals()) 

    for index in range(0,len(dirs)):
        dirname = dirs[index]
        q = "select _ROWID_,* from resultdf where "+ dirname +" != mode_average"
        diffs = pysqldf(q)      
        if (len(diffs) >0):
            print ("Advisor "+dirname+ " had deviations in "+filename)
            diffs.to_csv(dirname+"_"+filename+"_deviation.csv",index = False)        
            print(diffs)
    resultdf.to_csv("Comparison_of_"+filename ,index=False)
```